# Is it possible to specify name of .rmd file when knitting/rendering in r-markdown?

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

After knitting to a word doc, I would like to specify the name of the .rmd file when it is saved. For instance I have set the name of the word doc to include date and time so that each word doc version is saved as a different file:

```
'''{r}
 knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) { rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = 
 encoding, output_file = paste0(substr(inputFile,1,nchar(inputFile)-4),'_',lubridate::today(),'_',paste0(lubridate::hour(lubridate::now()), lubridate::minute(lubridate::now())),'.docx')) })
'''
```

So in my directory I have the following:

FileName_2019-05-27_1741.docx
FileName.rmd
FileName_2019-05-27_1329.docx
FileName_2019-05-26_1420.docx

I'd like to have the .rmd files automatically saved the same way with date and time in case I want to go back and look at an earlier version of my .rmd file.

Comment: In the same chunk you could simply copy the RMD file and rename it?

Comment: That could work - is there code available to do this?

Comment: I think I've got it... `file.copy(from = "FileName.rmd", to = paste0('FileName_',lubridate::today(),'_',paste0(lubridate::hour(lubridate::now()), lubridate::minute(lubridate::now())),'.rmd'))` Thanks for the copying tip :)

Comment: I just saw your comments. Glad you have figured it out on your own :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked for me thanks to an earlier tip to copy/rename the file (I was looking for ways to save the file as opposed to copying):

```
file.copy(from = "FileName.rmd", 
          to = paste0('FileName_',lubridate::today(),'_',paste0(lubridate::hour(lubridate::now()), 
          lubridate::minute(lubridate::now())),'.rmd'))
```

I entered this in a new code chunk as I couldn't figure out how to do it within the header (which is where I had the code to name the word file). It does exactly what I need it to do now!